# How to share in social media from a Vuejs app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, facebook-social-plugins

I am using vue-social-sharing library for sharing in social media and it works fine but the only problem that I am encountering is that I can't share my article title, description, and image on Facebook. When I press the facebook share button it shares my website image title and og:description instead of my particular article.

```
var SocialSharing = require('vue-social-sharing');
Vue.use(SocialSharing);

<social-sharing url="https://vuejs.org/"
  title="The Progressive JavaScript Framework"
  description="Intuitive, Fast and Composable MVVM for building interactive interfaces."
  quote="Vue is a progressive framework for building user interfaces."
  hashtags="vuejs,javascript,framework"
  twitter-user="vuejs"
  inline-template>
<network network="facebook">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
</network>
<network network="twitter">
  <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter
</network>
```

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow to pass title and description (it retrieves them itself via the og tags in the url), check docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#params_share

Comment: I know that facebook retrieves them via og tags but how can I share for example a car from my website with a car image and title. I have tried to modify og tags with javascript but facebook crowler does not wait for a js script to load so it can't see the change.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet but i'm pretty sure changing the meta dynamically might help. Try using https://github.com/ktquez/vue-head or just plain Js:

```
var metaList = document.getElementsByTagName("META");
 metaList[0].setAttribute("content","noarchive");
```

And then re-parse the XFBML on the page using Facebook's JavaScript SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

To re-parse all of the XFBML on a page, you can call:

```
FB.XFBML.parse()
```

Alternately, to only evaluate a portion of a document, you can pass in a single element.

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('foo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Facebook doesn't scrap javascript yet. Look into prerendering or serversider rendering.

Comment: I know about prerendering but it is not suitable with dynamic pages, for example pages that have different id's. As it is to nuxt.js, I cant rewrite the whole project on nuxt.js because the project is already big right now. I just thought is there any other alternative to do that.

Comment: You don't need to rewrite the whole project for server side rendering. You change some basic config, and a few other adjustments per page.

Comment: @BernardDoci have you found a solution for that maybe? I have a lot of dynamic pages (job board) and I can't just pre-render every single page

Comment: @jeand'arme the only way to solve this problem is through SSR. The easiest way to do SSR is using nuxt.js or if your project is already on going you can try to make some configuration for example: https://medium.com/frontend-fun/vuejs-server-side-render-with-vue-router-e73d51699873

Comment: Thanks @BernardDoci - is it very hard to migrate Vue.js project over to Nuxt.js?

Comment: @jeand'arme One of the solutions I have tried and it worked fine was with htaccess in php laravel. I have redirected particular incoming requests in htaccess to go to the empty html page with desired meta tags. This method worked fine for me but I think the proper way to do it is still with SSR.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most JAM-stack friendly solutions would be:

**A**)
To use Edge workers (e.g. what AWS or CloudFlare offer) - that way you can catch a specific user-agent (bots) and serve them back only static HTML (could even be with an empty body, just the required meta tags). For others, you just let the request fall through without computing at the edge, so normal content is served. [This](https://medium.com/@MilkMan/rich-social-sharing-for-your-serverless-react-app-with-lambda-edge-15463c3e88ad) article explains the approach in further detail.

If you're hosted on Firebase, you can use [http triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) to achieve dynamic meta tags. Here's an excellent [write-up](https://medium.com/@jalalio/dynamic-og-tags-in-your-statically-firebase-hosted-polymer-app-476f18428b8b)  on it.

**B**) To use a serverless function that spins up a headless browser instance (like puppeteer) and snaps a screenshot with it. Zeit even has a [service](https://zeit.co/blog/social-og-image-cards-as-a-service) for this.

Note that both options use `puppeteer-core` to keep the end-bundle size and performance as low as possible